# .NET - Get video stream from a windows phone working as IP Camera

Tags: .net, camera, windows-phone

I'd like to build a .NET desktop application which could get the video stream in real time from the camera of a windows phone, throught wifi or bluetooth.

I found this http://www.senstic.com/wp7/PocketCam/PocketCam.aspx app, now how could I wire it to my application ? I thought of using a MediaElement to show and control the stream, but how can I wire the two together ?

I havn't much knowledge on windows phone development and absolutely no idea on how to get this video stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an IP webcam app and an MJPEG decoding library
http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/

Works very well and fairly simple to use. No audio streaming, but no compression (apart from each frame compression which can be disabled by setting the IP camera app quality to 100%) so faster response time. MJPEG is very good for real time

Comment: Also, MJPEG streaming apps are available for free on all mobile platforms

Answer (score -1):

I am also trying to do such thing in windows phone. Eventually, I figure it out by capturing images from your video at regular interval work as fps. Like you want 10 images per second then try to send image at every 10 milli second through sockets.

It work like a ImageStreamingServer for you. A .Net implementation of image Streaming server is available for .Net online [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server). You can read and modify there source code to create such server.

Comment: This link leads to a project that uses Android and MJPG streaming. This does not seem to match the OPs question well